# proportion of suppliers formula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

im sitting on this question: what proportion of suppliers are from germany? i have to solve the question using a formula on google sheets

i have a spreadsheet with the suppliers here:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nlDE2zxg1L9u6I2BE1wqo5_bPUqChiY1N1qogtIlXS0/edit?usp=sharing

my idea was to enter the formula: =PERCENTIF(I2:I30,"Germany") but i get an error. Could someone tell me what im doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Change "," to ";" in the formula you entered

Comment: still does not work :( i still get parse error :(

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=PERCENTIF(I2:I30;"Germany")
```

and see if that works?

[image]